# How to run the same job against multiple repositories with multiple triggers?

Tags: bamboo

So I'm actively trying to circumvent the job limit bamboo has in place because I have many inactive repositories that get fixed occasionally when new platform updates come out or a one-off new feature is added.

What I would like to happen is for my repository polling to pick up that there's been a change on one of my repository branches, run the job, and presto-change-o we're back to square 1 where I'm listening again for another repository polling update from another change.

Example:

- Repo 1 has a commit pushed
- Bamboo "hears" the change and starts the job
- Repo 2 has a commit pushed
- Bamboo hears  this change as well, but doesn't continue due to 1 agent being available, this change is queued for later
- Repo 1's triggered update finishes and publishes an artifact that can be shared
- Bamboo resolves and starts Repo 2's job

Is doing something like this even possible? The best solution (meh) that I've found thus far is to just create one job with a sequential build where it's basically checkout/build/checkout/build/checkout/build but that would result in having to run through many unnecessary steps should I poll only one update from one repository. It's not like these things are changing frequently.

Comment: Do you need different jobs for different repositories? Can't you generalize the same job to work on different repositories (presuming repos have the same project).

Comment: No; sorry I somehow missed that. That's kind of the point. I have one job that's general enough to build an artifact that I need for every repository. I just don't know how to set it up such that each repository can use the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple repositories to your build plan, and in your repository polling trigger put checkboxes on all repositories added into the plan.

To add multiple repositories,

1. Open Plan Configuration Editing
2. Select third tab "Repositories"
3. Press "Add repository" button.
4. Configure your repository and save.
5. Select fourth tab "Triggers".
6. Open your Repository Polling trigger and select all repositories you've added on steps 3-4.
7. Save the trigger.

Then repository polling has to check all configured repos, according to documentation:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO058/Triggering+builds

You can also add additional repositories into Source code checkout task, and checkout every repository in different subdirectory.
E.g. for repos `R1`, `R2`, `R3` you will have working copy directories `./W1`, `./W2`, `./W3`.

And Then it's up to you - either you clone your assembler task `T` to `T1`, `T2`, `T3` to make builds from each working copy correspondingly, then it will be done for all jobs on every commit, they will all produce artifacts with the same build number, or you can add a shell script task and write a shell script which discovers the latest commit among all working copies (let's assume it is `./W2`), creates symbolic link to that working copy subdirectory as `./MySymbolicLink`, and your job that assembles the build will do that from `./MySymbolicLink` folder.

Comment: How does this integrate into the job? I was just reading up on [checking out code](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/checking-out-code-289277060.html) trying to figure this out. It sounds like if I have a source code check out task in my job, it will check out every single repository every time the job is triggered <?>

Comment: Ah, I've got what you mean. Yes, Source code checkout will do checkout only from the selected repository.

Comment: Updated the answer.